# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS from htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I change the .htaccess file and I added this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but when I try to access the page, it gives me this error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I cleared all my cache and cookies, I tried it with another browser, and it didn't work.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

It appears that some versions of the apache http servers ssl module do *not* set the `%{HTTPS}` variable, quite in contrast to what the documentation claims. Have a try using this alternative:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 0):

Add `RewriteEngine On` to your first line, vai parecer assim:

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Last line you could change to something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
```

Where `https://www.website.com` add your own domain.

That should send you on the right way

Comment: If that were the issue, the error message certainly would be something different, if an error would occur at all.

Comment: He could change the last line to something like: ```RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1``` where "www.website.com" he would write his own domain name.

Comment: Absolutely, I agree that the OP could do that. However I do not see why that should change anything.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't have a valid SSL cert?

Comment: Sure, might be possible, but again: that would result in a different error message, right? That would be a client side error then, the client refusing to connect.